# cant execute simple bash script on raspberry pi (raspbian)

Tags: linux, bash

Ok, so basically i have created the script by going to bin in the terminal and typing in

```
sudo nano mytesterscript.sh
```

From there i wrote the script and saved it.
To make it executable, i then used the command

```
    chmod +x mytesterscript.sh
```

then when i wanted to execute it by using

```
./mytesterscript.sh
```

I get the error:

```
bin/bash: bad interperter:no such file or directory
```

I can execute the script by typing

```
bash mytesterscript.sh
```

but i want to be able to do it like

```
./mytesterscript.sh
```

Any ideas guys?

```
#!bin/bash
#declare $STRING Variable
STRING= "Hello world"
#print variable on screen
echo $STRING
```

Comment: What is content of `mytesterscript.sh`? Looks like shebang is incorrect.

Comment: its just a script that says hello world

Comment: Can you please edit your question and post scripts full content?

Comment: @user3662438, Notice the difference between your first line, and my answer. You are missing the `/` in front of the `bin`.

Comment: Thanks guys for the help it works now seems pretty stupid i just missed out a / :)

Answer (score 4):

Make sure the top of your script says:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Observe the `/` in front of `bin`.

If that does not work, try `which bash` and use that output.

Comment: Thanks guys for the help it works now seems pretty stupid i just missed out a / :)

Comment: @user3662438, It happens to the best of us, and one character is *very hard to spot*.

Answer (score -1):

have happened to me right now :D But solution is not in 1st line but in space

```
# replace:
STRING= "Hello world"

# by:

STRING="Hello world"
```

Took me approximately hour of struggling :D